# How should I go about doing this proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to mathematical proofs and would like some help understanding how to prove 
$$
\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A = A^c
$$

I would like to see a proof if possible. I understand that we need to prove equality of the two sides which is done by making sure both sides are subsets of each other.

Comment: One way might be to use a "truth table" setup: an element is in a set is represented as "true" and otherwise it is "false"

Comment: Venn Diagrams help when only considering two sets.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Although you are new to mathematical proofs, you can surely provide some more details about this: where did you find this problem, what do you already understand here? Do you fail to understand the notation or do you just want to see a proof? In any case, this site asks you to show what you think would be a good proof strategy. This helps others to help you!

Comment: a proof would be nice, I understand what the question is asking but am finding it difficult to formulate a proof.

Comment: This is just an instance of the [absorption law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections).

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{gt6989b}$'s method is probably the one you'll want to use for a beginner proof. Alternatively, you could do this with some set algebra. We can use the identity $$C \setminus D = C \cap D^c$$ to rewrite your equation as $$\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A  = \left(A^c \cup B^c\right) \cap A^c $$ Can you proceed from here using the distributive law of set algebra?

Comment: I haven't learnt that before.

Comment: if you could so me the proof it would be nice.

Comment: @ArjunDhiman Your proof? Or the set algebra properties I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

**hints**

Every time you need to prove equality of two sets, $A=B$, you must show

1. If $a \in A$, then $a \in B$.
2. If $b \in B$, then $b \in A$.

In your case, the first part starts out like this this. Let $x \in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A$. Now prove $x \not \in A$.

Then, let $y \not \in A$ and prove that $y \in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A$.

**UPDATE**

Note that since $x \in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A$, and the last operation ($-A$) removes all elements of $A$ from consideration, what can be said about $x$?

**Update 2** Can you prove that if $x \in Z - A$ for any set $Z$, then $x \not \in A$? This will finish part 1.

Now for part 2, let $y \in A^c$. Thus, $y \in A^c \cup B^c$ (why?), and since $y \not \in A$, removing $A$ from the set does not affect the presence of $y$, hence, $y \in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A$ as desired.

Comment: yeah, that is what i have so far. After that im lost.

Comment: @ArjunDhiman see update, note also $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c$

Comment: that x only belongs to B.

Comment: @ArjunDhiman What if $x$ isn't in $A$ _or_ $B$?

Comment: wouldn't it be in the universe then ? so all element outside of sets A and B.

Comment: @ArjunDhiman see last update

Answer (score 0):

Trivially $\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) - A\subseteq U-A = A^c$; (because $\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) \subseteq U$, where $U$ is universal set).

---

For Proof of  $ A^c\subseteq\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) $, we can use two facts:
fact. 1- By [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), $\left(A^c \cup B^c\right)=\left(A\cap B\right)^c$.
fact. 2- If $T \subseteq S$ then $S^c \subseteq  T^c$.
Now
Let $\color{red}{x\in A^c}$. By "fact 2", $x\in \left(A\cap B\right)^c$. By "fact 1", $\color{red}{x\in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right)}$. So $x\in \left(A^c \cup B^c\right)-A$